# Container becomes 50% transparent when dragged

Tags: drag-and-drop, codenameone

I tried dragging containers, but when dragged they become 50% transparent. When dropped, they become normal again.

How can I avoid this? So that they stay fully opaque during all the dragging process

I don't have any code to provide as it's simply a question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/Component.java#L4738-L4753). You can override the method to change the behavior but that seems redundant for such a small change.

That's why I made [this change](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/7e859c279443288ba65b75fd4f179101c61c3952) which after the Friday update (March 22, 2024) will let you write this:

```
Component.setDefaultDragTransparency((byte)255);
```